# if an Alarm is registered (as a reminder) for a custom task, would the alarm be deleted if the task is removed?

Tags: android, task, alarm, alarmmanager

I'm hoping to make [another] tasks list app, with ability to set reminders on each task. The tasks would be stored in a SQLite DB, but what about the alarms? Should they be (or can they be) stored in the DB too?

If the app is uninstalled, with tasks which have reminders in the future, will these alarms still go off?

The ability to modify an existing time/date of a reminder is important (and also offset the alarm (comparable to a snooze option on an alarm clock) by a user specified amount, though I guess I could reset a new alarm).

My question pertains mostly to the storage (and management) of alarms, or am I thinking about alarms in an incorrect way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can se the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) . But you have to store your alarms localy in DB for an example and then register them via AlarmManager so that at particular time an intent can be fired.

You can see [this](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129) tutorial or search for "alarmmanager android example" in google.

Comment: Thanks for the link.

I assume I would store the calendar's time in milliseconds in the DB to store the time an alarm is due. But in the case that the user reboots his or her phone, the alarm will be lost, afaik.

My original question was probably really badly titled/worded; it was a two-parter warranting two separate questions. The main one relating to how alarms are stored/maintained:

On rebooting a phone, is there a way to register the alarms that were stored in the DB, i.e. by forcing a particular activity in my app to open (even in background), to re-register all the alarms.

Comment: using an on boot receiver would fix this, [http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/dc7b365e8d293708 ], [http://www.dev-articles.com/article/Android+Boot+Receiver-20001 ]

Comment: You can store the alarm in your DB as date for an example 2011-03-29 14:00:00 and then to substract the current date with this date. Thatway you will get the miliseconds and then you can register the intent via AlarmManager. The alarm is lost when your application is uninstalled or the phone reboots. Therefore you need to register a Broadcast reciever for boot, so that the device reboots, your reciever will fire up, will check the DB and will register all alarms.

Comment: so, do we have to create the alarms through the `AlarmManager` and also to store them in the DB, so every time we reboot the phone, the alarms are gonna be created again?